# Typing math formulas in LaTex and getting them in MathType format?

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-office, latex, libreoffice, mathtype

I am asked to type some math formulas that can work in Microsoft Office and MathType equation editor.

But I only have access to Ubuntu 12.04 near me, there is LibreOffice available under Ubuntu as well, but I am used to type math formulas in LaTex.

So I wonder how to provide math formulas that will work in Microsoft Office and MathType, if I work under Ubuntu, preferably with LaTex but LibreOffice being also acceptable since it is still under Ubuntu?

Thanks and regards!